# How to accommodate different types of unique identifiers in a table?

Tags: sql-server-2008, database-design

I currently have a table that has an `IDENTITY` field. The field is declared as an `INT` type. The problem is that I have some new unique values, but they are not `INT`. They are alpha-numeric, so I can't put them in the `INT` field. Is my only option to create another column and stick these in a new `NON-IDENTITY` column or is there an alternative? The example above is just for 2 different identity formats, but what if I start getting more? I don't want to have to create a column for every type of formatted alpha(number).

Answer (score 0):

It's not uncommon for a table to have more than one column that must also be unique.  I think the real question is what level of normalization are you shooting for here and does adding that column support or break your targeted level of relationship normalization or what you deem acceptable?

For example considering 3rd normal and/or the famous "every non key attribute will reveal a fact about the key, the whole key, and nothing but the key.... *so help me Codd*".

Does the new unique value you are adding add a fact about the row identified by the key or not?

Further the primary key is typically the clustered index, but it doesn't have to be.  You can also set up other unique indexes on the same table and this is considered 'ok' within the context of 
"what are you trying to accomplish" and be optimized for.

Comment: No, it does not add value.  One user just uses numbers that we create and another user provides us the unique values, which happen to be alpha-numeric values.

Comment: Apparently it adds a fact relied upon by the one user and not by the other.  So, based on your business rules and agreements with users it could still be fine.  With regards to database-design... 'ok' is what you define as acceptable for your situation and agreed service levels - outside of some grossly bad practices of course.

Comment: In practice your true fight here may be convincing users to use the same identifiers to reduce maintenance and headaches associated with data.

Comment: LOL, I wish, but that is impossible, it is the government.

Comment: Well said, you may just have to build the extra column then :)

Answer (score 0):

The alternative is to:

1. Create a temporary table with the exact same scheme as your old table
2. Copy the values of your table to the new temp table
3. Drop the old table
4. Create a new table based on the scheme of your old table, but with a textual identity
5. Copy data from the temp table to the newly created table with the textual identity
6. Drop the temporary table

Of course you must pay attention to any potential actions regarding this table in the process.

Comment: I need to have both integral ids and textual ids.

Comment: Then your integral id should be the identity and the other, textual field should have a unique constraint.

Comment: Or you can define a primary key constraint which would contain the two fields, but then you need a unique constraint for each of the fields to ensure their uniqueness.